# Align Arabic and English text in the same line in Crystal Reports

Tags: c#, crystal-reports

I'm working on a Crystal Reports project where I need to display English and Arabic text on the same line with proper alignment (English left-aligned and Arabic right-aligned). How can I achieve this within a single text object or formula? Manual alignment with separate text boxes has proved unreliable.

What I'm trying to achieve

```
LeftAligned(EnglishText) + RightAligned(ArabicText)
```

Is there a way to concatenate the text with correct alignment in Crystal Reports?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think this is possible using a single object or field.  Alignment is a property of the object, and a single object can't have both left and right alignment, it can only be one or the other.

I would approach this problem by duplicating the section into two sections, then set them to overlay each other.  One section will contain data in English with left alignment and the other section will contain data in Arabic with right alignment.  You just need to ensure fields cannot grow to ensure the two sets of data line up horizontally.